# Scheduling daily task with node-cron not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, node-cron

I'm trying to create an api that returns a random song of the day. I'm trying to schedule the randomize function to run once a day to pick a new song for that day. I'm using node-cron to do this. This function is running way more than once a day, however. It appears to be running more like once an hour, but I'm not certain how often its running. The api is hosted on Heroku if that makes any difference.

```
const cron = require('node-cron');

let usedSongs = [];
let use;

function randomize() {
    if(usedSongs.length === 169) {
        usedSongs = [];
    };
    let test = Math.round(Math.random(0,1) * 169);
    usedSongs.includes(test) ? randomize() : use = String(test);
    usedSongs.push(test)
};
randomize();

cron.schedule('0 0 0 * * *', () => {
    randomize();
}, {scheduled: true,
    timezone: 'America/New_York'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be calling randomize() twice - once just after the method definition (which will run probably every time the server starts(?), and again inside the scheduler - which should fire once per day as expected.

```
function randomize() {
    if(usedSongs.length === 169) {
        usedSongs = [];
    };
    let test = Math.round(Math.random(0,1) * 169);
    usedSongs.includes(test) ? randomize() : use = String(test);
    usedSongs.push(test)
};
randomize();    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

cron.schedule('0 0 0 * * *', () => {
    randomize();     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}, {scheduled: true,
    timezone: 'America/New_York'
});
```